# Using an extended usermodel, how can I create two model instances with two modelforms in the same view?

Tags: python, django

First off, I want to say that I am new to django though I understand most of it,  forms have always been confusing to me.

I have two models in which I need to create an instance from, the standard built in `User` model and my own `UserProfile` model.

The problem I am facing is that really do not know how to display two forms (one for each model) in the template and on `save()` then tell django that the newly created `UserProfile` instance's `User = model.ForeignKey` belongs to the also newly created `User`.

My forms.py is fairly simple:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile

class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class  UserProfileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('display_name', 'avatar', 'birthday', 'usertype', 'daw', 'usergenre')
```

In my views.py I've tried doing this:

```
from .forms import UserForm
from .forms import UserProfileForm

# Create your views here.
def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form2.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form})
```

But when I try to access `/register` I get this error:
http://dpaste.com/19NH2A6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit `/register` page from browser, your view gets `GET` request, you have created form only for `POST` request

```
from .forms import UserForm
from .forms import UserProfileForm

# Create your views here.
def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='uf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='upf')
        if form.is_valid():
            if form2.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserForm(prefix='uf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(prefix='upf')            

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form2})
```

Comment: This worked, however now when I hit submit, I get this error: http://dpaste.com/1WTKPHJ

Comment: from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect see @Çağatay Barın

Answer (score 2):

You should use save() method.
Next time you have a problem, check the official Django documentation.
[ModelForms - save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

```
from .forms import UserForm
from .forms import UserProfileForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, prefix='uf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='upf')
        if form.is_valid():
            if form2.is_valid():
                form.save()
                form2.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserForm(prefix='uf')
        form2 = UserProfileForm(prefix='upf')            

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form, 'form2': form2})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the traceback yourself so that you can find the error easily.
It says;

> Exception Type: NameError at /register/
>   Exception Value: name 'HttpResponseRedirect' is not defined

You've used HttpResponseRedirect but you didn't import it, therefore it is not defined.

Add this to top of your code.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

Comment: I didn't even know that was something you had to import. Forgive me for asking, but how do I save the models after the POST request?

Comment: it's ok since you're new to django. When you see an error, just check the traceback. usually top of it might be meaningless but read the last 2-3 rows. If you don't understand the error, google it. If you still can't find the answer, then you can ask here :)

Comment: Thing is, google wasn't giving me any easy to understand answers, so that's why I asked. I googled why it wasn't saving the model instances too, no luck.